# Apache2 at VPS without domain

Tags: apache, vps

I want to use Apache2 at VPS to host my test websites.
Now I have a Joomla website and can reach it using `111.111.111.111/mydomain.com`
But the troubles becomes when I trying to reach website's page like `111.111.111.111/mydomain.com/about.html`

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

I think I need to configure apache right way but I don't know how.
Yes I know I can register some domain name but I prefer to use `111.111.111.111/mydomain.com` address for now.
Thank you.

Comment: Of course, `about.html` will become a path of `111.111.111.111`, not `mydomain.com`. Have you tried `mydomain.com%2Fabout.html`? Else I think you should find another way!

Comment: Thank you for response. ```mydomain.com%2Fabout.html``` does not work. I thought there is a some way to make website accept ```111.111.111.111/mydomain.com``` as single website address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attemptions I had resolved it.
First of all you need to check the *apache2.conf* file. There must be active string `AllowOverride All` .

And next block

`<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>`

Then you need activate rewrite module

`sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

And better restart your Virtual Machine.